# Vaadin Elements Grid - Row Details Generator

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-grid

I'm trying to create a row editor.

When using the default example code for the grid [link](https://vaadin.com/vaadin-documentation-portlet/elements/vaadin-grid/vaadin-grid-row-details.html), when I'm styling my element im not able to do `width: 100%` the td the element is appended onto has the correct `colspan` in my case 6 but the width of the element is no where near the width of the 6 columns. The width feels more like one column.

Comment: You might want to try out the version 2.0 preview: https://cdn.vaadin.com/vaadin-core-elements/preview/vaadin-grid/demo/

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I've just went with using a popup. 2.0 looks awesome but do you have any estimate of when it will be "production ready"

Comment: We're aiming to release stable in February 2017

Answer (score 0):

Can you set `display: flex` for the row details for it to take full space? You can find an example here: https://cdn.vaadin.com/vaadin-core-elements/master/vaadin-grid/demo/other.html

Comment: No setting `display: flex` doesn't change the size at all -  it's parent `<td colspan="6">` has a width much smaller then colspan="6" suggests.